# C++ Trying to generate every possible set of points given max/min x/y/z values, n number of points to be in set, and m value to increment by

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, point

I posted this question before but I think I explained it very poorly. Essentially, I want to generate all possible point sets of size n containing points inside the area bounded by the origin (0,0,0) and a point (Y1,Y2,Y3) given by the user, with a set value m to increment by.

For example, if n is 3, m is 1, and (Y1,Y2,Y3) is (1,1,1), the generated point sets would be (each row being a set):

```
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (1, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 0) & (1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (1, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0) & (0, 0, 1) & (1, 1, 1)

.......

(1, 1, 1) & (1, 1, 1) & (1, 1, 1)
```

This is what I initially tried but it's only really doing what I want for each individual point, and not finding the correct overall sets (pointset is a vector of point objects of size n that has already been created in the main program, with each point initialized to (0,0,0)):

```
void allPoints(double Y1, double Y2, double Y3, double precision, vector<Point> pointset)
{
int count = pointset.size()-1;

while (count>=0)
{
    while (pointset.at(count).getX()<Y1) //runs through every possible rectangle within rectangle created by given point Y and origin
    {
        while (pointset.at(count).getY()<Y2)
        {
            while (pointset.at(count).getZ()<Y3)
            {
                // insert formula to test each set with here
                pointset.at(count).incZ(precision);

            }
            pointset.at(count).setZ(0);
            pointset.at(count).incY(precision);
        }
        pointset.at(count).setY(0);
        pointset.at(count).incX(precision);

    }
    count--;
}


}
```

I can go through later and omit any sets that contain duplicate points. In the end I will be going through and testing each point set with a specific formula and then comparing all resulting values, but I know how to do that.

I only really have basic Java/C++ experience and I'm having trouble writing the correct loop, although I feel like the solution here is similar and I'm just missing it. I'm assuming I'd want to use a vector of point objects in this situation.

Any help getting me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow deals with software problems. You haven't reached a software problem yet, so you are at a disadvantage. You can post a "This is my plan, anyone see problems with it?" question or you can post a "I have been through the following research looking for a viable solution to my problem and am stuck. Where should I look next ? <research goes here>" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are just counting using base Y1, Y2 and then Y3 and storing the results, so you can use `std::list<unsigned short[3]>` of size n and count like you would count in base 10 (in when you reach Y1, you reset the row to 0 and set the next one to 1). When an int[3] is full you know you need to empty it and go to the next int[3].

You'll need a `countBase(const unsigned short& base)` function that increment a value in every cycle of loop and reset it when it reaches `base`, then increment the next value. Your program ends when every values in the list are equal to Y1, Y2 or Y3.

I don't know what you are planning to do with this but you can, on each execution of the loop, display of store the state of the std::list.

Don't forget that what you are doing is pretty much like counting in your own strange base and storing the result, and it shouldn't be hard

[EDIT]
After looking at your edit, I definitely think you should use only one loop, a container of ushort[3], a way to increment up to `base` and find a way to keep the result, it would be much easier to read, and it should give you exactly what you want.

[EDIT]
I think it would also be faster to use a std::list and for this kind of project, you probably need some performances.